# how do we start timestamp from yesterday

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using this line in where statement

```
event_timestamp > UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 28 DAY))
```

it gives me results from today until the last 28 days. But today's data is not complete so I want from yesterday until last 28 days.

I want something like

```
event_timestamp > UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP_SUB((CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1), INTERVAL 28 DAY))
```

Can someone support? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can write where statement with two condition

```
where event_timestamp > UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 28 DAY)) and event_timestamp < UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(current_timestamp,DAY))
```

TIMESTAMP_TRUNC will truncate the timestamp to start off today's timestamp. that is to 00:00 hrs.